# How to calculate gauge pressure at water depth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

I am creating a program that will calculate danger at water depths for sensitive equipment and maybe humans.

How do I calculate the gauge pressure at a depth $D$. Lets say $D = 5000$ meters.

My guess is to calculate the atmospheric pressure so I can find the $Pa$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hydrostatic pressure at any height below the water surface is calculated by 
$P=hdg$ where $h$ is the height below the open water surface, $d$ is the density of water and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. So if you want to calculate gauge pressure at height $h$ then use formula
$P=hdg+P^\circ$  where $P^\circ$ is atmospheric pressure.

Comment: $p°$ changes depending on the depth right? If so how do I find it?

Comment: Except for' rho' a Greek letter used to denote density of substance, I have used 'd' for density

Comment: Is $p°$ pressure at surface?

Comment: No , p° do not change with depth. It  is atmospheric pressure exerted by atmosphere on water surface . it remains constant. It will change if you go upper and upper in air.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the accepted answer:

The ***gauge*** pressure, $P_{gauge}$ at a depth $H$ in a fluid of density $D$, where the acceleration of gravity is $g$, is given by:$$P_{gauge}=DgH$$
since the gauge pressure is the difference between the absolute pressure and the current atmospheric pressure.

The absolute pressure is the gauge pressure, ***measured against vacuum***.  So, starting in space, you descend to sea level through the atmosphere, and experience an increase to (naturally) one atmosphere absolute pressure.  As you go down through the water to any depth, the hydrostatic  pressure gradually adds to the surface atmospheric pressure.  So the absolute pressure at depth, $P_{abs}$ is given by:$$P_{abs}=P_{atmos}+DgH$$